# How to set image to Google Play Books API thumbnail using Fresco?

Tags: android, fresco

I am trying to load in a Google Play books image thumbnail from a URL using Fresco (I've also tried using Glide and Picasso) 1.10.0. I am able to load in another image (such as this https://i.imgur.com/6zDqjm8.jpg), but only the placeholder image shows when I use the Google Play Books thumbnail link (e.g. http://books.google.com/books/content?id=F1wgqlNi8AMC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api).

I've also tried adding ".jpeg" on to the end of the link (since in a web browser the image still shows) in the Uri.parse code, but it doesn't make a difference.

Do you know why this is and/or what I am doing wrong?

I have got the INTERNET permission in my manifest. I also have the Fresco namespace in my XML file.

My Fresco code (taken from [Getting Started with Fresco](http://frescolib.org/docs/index.html)  guide):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://books.google.com/books/content?id=F1wgqlNi8AMC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api");
SimpleDraweeView draweeView = findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
draweeView.setImageURI(uri);
```

XML code for the SimpleDraweeView:

```
 <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
        android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/search_white_24dp" />
```

JSON I'm working with (for more Google Play Books thumbnails): https://pastebin.com/hq4AFMRb

Please let me know if you need any more information (e.g. XML). I don't mind using a different third-party library (including Glide or Picasso) if that works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like, that unprotected traffic is no longer available for making requests to the Google Books servers (Pay attention at the piece of the Glide's log below):

> 08-09 22:31:06.428 7606-7606/com.sandbox.test W/Glide: Load failed for
>   http://books.google.com/books/content?id=F1wgqlNi8AMC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api
>   with size [2392x2392]
>       class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
>       There were 2 causes:
>       java.io.IOException(**Cleartext HTTP traffic to books.google.com not permitted**)
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException(No content provider: http://books.google.com/books/content?id=F1wgqlNi8AMC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api)
>        call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
>         Cause (1 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed,
>   class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
>       There was 1 cause:

So, you can just add the **"S"** letter to pictures url protocol from the API and make a request through **HTTPS**.

In my case, this did the trick.